# Dimension of scale, or depth - does it exist?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime-dimensions

Description of an object in 3 standard space dimensions seems not to be its full description. Say, the placement of a molecule is described by $x=2N$, $y=4N$, $z=7N$ measurement units in the Descartes coordinates.

If this is the maximal level of our measurement precision, both a single atom within the molecule and the atomic nucleus will be described by the same $2N$, $4N$,  $7N$.

To fixate the different orders of magnitude of the size of these different, though embedded objects, we need an additional dimension of depth. This dimension is directed upwards and downwards the scale levels, showing the place of an object on the ladder of the scale hierarchy in the Universe. My question is this:

> *Do we really need to introduce the 4D system of space coordinates, including the special scale dimension, or it is enough just to say that an object is smaller or bigger, or refine our measurement precision?*

Comment: Aren't you just saying that different parts of a molecule are at different positions in space?

Comment: Not just at different positions on the same structural level, but at different levels of micro- macro scale

Comment: Did you mean _4D system of spacetime coordinates_ rather than _4D system of space coordinates?_

Comment: I am discussing only space coordinates here. The standard Descartes set is 3D, I suggest to add one more D, namely, the scale, or depth D, depicting the position of an object on the particular level of the general micro- macro scale from the Planck bottom level up to the presumably upper galactic megaclusters level. If to add time, it makes 4D of space coordinates plus 1D of time, altogether 5D.